# HYPER-V VM disappered after reboot

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, anti-virus

I have WIN 2016 server (datacenter), on which one VM hosting DHCP Server disappered after rebooting host server.

I tried restarting the VMMS services but no luck. I have two antivirus running on the server McAfee & FireEye. As its a DHCP server disabling Antivirus was risky, and as the VM was in off condition, I uninstalled the hyper V Manager and tried installing it but now my host is in no boot.

Can some one please help on what may happened during reinstalling the Hyper-V Manager, what went wrong?? Plz Help..

Answer (score 0):

two antivirus on the same server is not right , and antivirus is not recommended to be installed on hyper-v host server i had a similar problem, in my client site the IT personal installed antivirus on the hyper-v host server without consulting me, after one month file server VM restarted with out any warring and fallback to a snapshot taken one month ago and it was caused by the antivirus.

Comment: Please consider structuring your post using sentences ending with a "." That will make it much easier for the reader to follow your thoughts.